# How to Select an Array Between a lot of String Array By Selected List Position in Android

Tags: java, android, arrays

Hi Everyone Im working on a bus times application. There are more than 570 bus lines in my city. I'm listing lines with a spinner but my problem is I dont want to use 570 if-then block. Im think use a variable "busline" and merging this variable with selected line's position. Like linename="busline"+selected position. But eclipse gives an error "Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable". So how can i select true array with variable. Or is there any easy way making this application. Thanks a lot.

Here is my code

```
final  String[] buslines={"Hat Seçiniz","720-AGIRNAS DNS","721-AGIRNAS GDS","275-AHİEVRAN DÖNÜŞ","275-AHİEVRAN GİDİŞ","263-AHİEVRAN KOCASİNAN SİNANKENT DÖNÜŞ","263-AHİEVRAN KOCASİNAN SİNANKENT GİDİŞ","470-AKİN-YAZIR DÖNÜŞ","470-AKİN-YAZIR GİDİŞ","742-AKMESCİT DNS","742-AKMESCİT GDS","323-ALTINOLUK ASRİMEZARLIK  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","323-ALTINOLUK ASRİMEZARLIK  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","324-ALTINOLUK ASRİMEZARLIK DÖNÜŞ","324-ALTINOLUK ASRİMEZARLIK GİDİŞ","326-ALTINOLUK ÇİFTEÖNÜ  DÖNÜŞ","326-ALTINOLUK ÇİFTEÖNÜ GİDİŞ","320-ALTINOLUK 5 YOL  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","320-ALTINOLUK 5 YOL  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","321-ALTINOLUK 5 YOL DÖNÜŞ","321-ALTINOLUK 5 YOL GİDİŞ","700-AMARAT DNS","700-AMARAT GDS","141-ANBAR AĞAÇİŞLERİ DÖNÜŞ","141-ANBAR AĞAÇİŞLERİ GİDİŞ","144-ANBAR HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","144-ANBAR HASTANE GİDİŞ","140-ANBAR İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","140-ANBAR İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","107-BAĞDAT YENİDOĞAN ALT GEÇİT HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","106-BAĞDAT YENİDOĞAN İSTASYON CAD. ÜST GEÇİT DÖNÜŞ","106-BAĞDAT YENİDOĞAN İSTASYON CAD. ÜST GEÇİT GİDİŞ","148-BASIN SİTESİ SELİMİYE FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","148-BASIN SİTESİ SELİMİYE FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","146-BASIN SİTESİ 30 AĞUSTOS FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","146-BASIN SİTESİ 30 AĞUSTOS FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","541-BAŞAKPINAR DAĞYOLU DÖNÜŞ","5410-BAŞAKPINAR DAĞYOLU DÖNÜŞ","5410-BAŞAKPINAR DAĞYOLU GİDİŞ","541-BAŞAKPINAR DAĞYOLU GİDİŞ","544-BAŞAKPINAR K.KÖPRÜ Ç.DERE  DAĞYOLU DÖNÜŞ","544-BAŞAKPINAR K.KÖPRÜ Ç.DERE  DAĞYOLU GİDİŞ","542-BAŞAKPINAR K.KÖPRÜ TALAS DÖNÜŞ","542-BAŞAKPINAR K.KÖPRÜ TALAS GİDİŞ","543-BAŞAKPINAR K.KÖRRÜ Ç.DERE TALAS DÖNÜŞ","543-BAŞAKPINAR K.KÖRRÜ Ç.DERE TALAS GİDİŞ","5411-BAŞAKPINAR KOOPERATİF TALAS GİDİŞ","540-BAŞAKPINAR TALAS DÖNÜŞ","5400-BAŞAKPINAR TALAS DÖNÜŞ","5400-BAŞAKPINAR TALAS GİDİŞ","540-BAŞAKPINAR TALAS GİDİŞ","221-BATTALGAZİ OSMANLI DÖNÜŞ","221-BATTALGAZİ OSMANLI GİDİŞ","220-BATTALGAZİ (YUKARI) DÖNÜŞ","220-BATTALGAZİ YUKARI GİDİŞ","802-BAYRAMHACI- YUVALI DNS","802-BAYRAMHACI- YUVALI GDS","56-BECEN MAH.  KARACAÖREN DÖNÜŞ","56-BECEN MAH.  KARACAÖREN GİDİŞ","57-BECEN MAH.  ZİNCİRLİ DÖNÜŞ","57-BECEN MAH.  ZİNCİRLİ GİDİŞ","58-BECEN MAH. GEDİZ CAD. DÖNÜŞ","58-BECEN MAH. GEDİZ CAD. GİDİŞ","55-BECEN MAH. IŞIK MEYDANI DÖNÜŞ","55-BECEN MAH. IŞIK MEYDANI GİDİŞ","605-BEDİR BAĞLARI DÖNÜŞ","605-BEDİR BAĞLARI GİDİŞ","340-BEĞENDİK ÇİFLİK DÖNÜŞ","340-BEĞENDİK ÇİFLİK GİDİŞ","130-BELSİN HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","132-BELSİN HASTANE FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","130-BELSİN HASTANE GİDİŞ","132-BELSİN HASTANEFAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","134-BELSİN İ.HATİP KÜMEEVLER DÖNÜŞ","134-BELSİN İ.HATİP KÜMEEVLER GİDİŞ","135-BELSİN KEYKUBAT HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","135-BELSİN KEYKUBAT HASTANE GİDİŞ","139-BELSİN KEYKUBAT İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","139-BELSİN KEYKUBAT İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","133-BELSİN KÜMEEVLER İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","133-BELSİN KÜMEEVLER İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","136-BELSİN KÜMEEVLER KEYKUBAT İMAMHATİP  GİDİŞ","136-BELSİN KÜMEEVLER KEYKUBAT İMAMHATİP DÖNÜŞ","500-BEYAZŞEHİR  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","500-BEYAZŞEHİR  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","503-BEYAZŞEHİR ÇEVREYOL HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","501-BEYAZŞEHİR DÖNÜŞ","501-BEYAZŞEHİR GİDİŞ","502-BEYAZŞEHİR VİP HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","502-BEYAZŞEHİR VİP HASTANE GİDİŞ","466-BİLLUR BAĞLARI DÖNÜŞ","466-BİLLUR BAĞLARI GİDİŞ","200-BOZTEPE  İSTASYON CAD. DÖNÜŞ","200-BOZTEPE  İSTASYON CAD. GİDİŞ","205-BOZTEPE ELAGÖZ FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","204-BOZTEPE ELAGÖZ İSTASYON CAD. DÖNÜŞ","204-BOZTEPE ELAGÖZ İSTASYON CAD. GİDİŞ","203-BOZTEPE HASTANE  DÖNÜŞ","203-BOZTEPE HASTANE GİDİŞ","730-BÜNYAN DNS","731-BÜNYAN GDS","438-CAMİİKEBİR  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","438-CAMİİKEBİR  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","435-CAMİİKEBİR DÖNÜŞ","435-CAMİİKEBİR GİDİŞ","436-CAMİİKEBİR HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","333-CEVİZLİ HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","333-CEVİZLİ HASTANE GİDİŞ","330-CEVİZLİ HASTANE KÜMEEVLER DÖNÜŞ","330-CEVİZLİ HASTANE KÜMEEVLER GİDİŞ","331-CEVİZLİ İMAMHATIP FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","331-CEVİZLİ İMAMHATIP FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","334-CEVİZLİ KÜMEEVLER HASTANE FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","334-CEVİZLİ KÜMEEVLER HASTANE FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","332-CEVİZLİ SİT. İMAMHATİP DÖNÜŞ","332-CEVİZLİ SİT. İMAMHATİP GİDİŞ","260-CIRGALAN DÖNÜŞ","260-CIRGALAN GİDİŞ","2601-CIRGALAN KÜMEEVLER DÖNÜŞ","326-ÇAĞŞAK KÜKÜRT DÖNÜŞ","326-ÇAĞŞAK KÜKÜRT GİDİŞ","90-ÇEVREYOL HASTANE  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","90-ÇEVREYOL HASTANE  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","92-ÇEVREYOL HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","92-ÇEVREYOL HASTANE GİDİŞ","91-ÇEVREYOL NATO FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","91-ÇEVREYOL NATO FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","478-ÇEVRİL DÖNÜŞ","478-ÇEVRİL GİDİŞ","327-ÇİFTEÖNÜ ALTINOLUK FAKÜLTE dönüş","3271-ÇİFTEÖNÜ ALTINOLUK FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","760-ÇİFTLİK DNS","760-ÇİFTLİK GDS","36-DANİŞMENT OSMANLI  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","36-DANİŞMENT OSMANLI  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","35-DANİŞMENT OSMANLI DÖNÜŞ","35-DANİŞMENT OSMANLI GİDİŞ","38-DANİŞMENT SOSYAL TESİS DÖNÜŞ","38-DANİŞMENT SOSYAL TESİS GİDİŞ","357-DOGU SANAYI DÖNÜŞ","357-DOGU SANAYI GİDİŞ","715-DÜVER- ELMALI DNS","715-DÜVER- ELMALI GDS","400-EBİÇ-DADAĞI DÖNÜŞ","400-EBİÇ-DADAĞI GİDİŞ","310-EĞRİBUCAK DÖNÜŞ","310-EĞRİBUCAK GİDİŞ","312-EĞRİBUCAK GÜL CAD.","311-EĞRİBUCAK HASANDAĞI DÖNÜŞ","311-EĞRİBUCAK HASANDAĞI GİDİŞ","740-ELBAŞI DNS","740-ELBAŞI GDS","290-EMEK İNÖNÜ HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","290-EMEK İNÖNÜ HASTANE GİDİŞ","291-EMEK İNÖNÜ İSTASYON CAD. FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","291-EMEK İNÖNÜ İSTASYON CAD. FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","474-EMMİLER-KEMER-TAŞHAN DÖNÜŞ","474-EMMİLER-KEMER-TAŞHAN GİDİŞ","553-ENDÜRLÜK DÖNÜŞ","553-ENDÜRLÜK GİDİŞ","554-ENDÜRLÜK GÜLİSTAN EVLERI DÖNÜŞ","554-ENDÜRLÜK GÜLİSTAN EVLERI GİDİŞ","415-ENGELLİLER KENTİ DÖNÜŞ","415-ENGELLİLER KENTİ GİDİŞ","4-ERCİYES DÖNÜŞ","4-ERCİYES GİDİŞ","460-ERENKOY DÖNÜŞ","460-ERENKOY GİDİŞ","461-ERENKÖY HAYMANA DÖNÜŞ","461-ERENKÖY HAYMANA GİDİŞ","462-ERENKÖY 3N SİTESİ GİDİŞ","485-ERKİLET  DERE MAH. DÖNÜŞ","485-ERKİLET  DERE MAH. GİDİŞ","446-ERKİLET  HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","447-ERKİLET  YENİ SANAYİ DÖNÜŞ","447-ERKİLET  YENİ SANAYİ GİDİŞ","449-ERKİLET ANAYOL YUKARI DÖNÜŞ","449-ERKİLET ANAYOL YUKARI GİDİŞ","486-ERKİLET DERE MAH. FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","486-ERKİLET DERE MAH. FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","443-ERKİLET ORTAYOL FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","443-ERKİLET ORTAYOL FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","440-ERKİLET ORTAYOL YUKARI DÖNÜŞ","440-ERKİLET ORTAYOL YUKARI GİDİŞ","445-ERKİLET 5 KATLI  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","445-ERKİLET 5 KATLI FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","448-ERKİLET 5 KATLI YUKARI DÖNÜŞ","448-ERKİLET 5 KATLI YUKARI GİDİŞ","121-ESENTEPE - HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","121-ESENTEPE - HASTANE GİDİŞ","127-ESENTEPE - HASTANE KOYUNCUBABA DÖNÜŞ","127-ESENTEPE - HASTANE KOYUNCUBABA GİDİŞ","128-ESENTEPE - İMAMHATİP KOYUNCUBABA DÖNÜŞ","129-ESENTEPE - İMAMHATİP KOYUNCUBABA FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","129-ESENTEPE - İMAMHATİP KOYUNCUBABA FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","128-ESENTEPE - İMAMHATİP KOYUNCUBABA GİDİŞ","125-ESENTEPE CEVİZLİ KÜMEEVLER İMAMHATİP DÖNÜŞ","125-ESENTEPE CEVİZLİ KÜMEEVLER İMAMHATİP GİDİŞ","122-ESENTEPE FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","122-ESENTEPE FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","120-ESENTEPE İMAMHATİP DÖNÜŞ","120-ESENTEPE İMAMHATİP GİDİŞ","51-ESENYURT  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","52-ESENYURT  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","53-ESENYURT BECEN MAH. DÖNÜŞ","53-ESENYURT BECEN MAH. GİDİŞ","50-ESENYURT DÖNÜŞ","50-ESENYURT GİDİŞ","8-FAKÜLTE İÇİ RİNG","10-FEVZİ ÇAKMAK YILDIZ SİT DÖNÜŞ","10-FEVZİ ÇAKMAK YILDIZ SİT GİDİŞ","386-FEVZİOĞLU AKÇATEPE GİDİŞ","385-FEVZİOĞLU DÖNÜŞ","385-FEVZİOĞLU GİDİŞ","390-GERMİR 06:00 DÖNÜŞ","390-GERMİR 06.00 GİDİŞ","390-GERMİR 06:30 DÖNÜŞ","390-GERMİR 06:30 GİDİŞ","520-GESİ DÖNÜŞ","520-GESİ GİDİŞ","521-GESİ GÜNEYLER DÖNÜŞ","521-GESİ GÜNEYLER GİDİŞ","522-GESİ VEKSE DÖNÜŞ","522-GESİ VEKSE GİDİŞ","111-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ALT GEÇIT GİDİŞ","111-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ALT GEÇİT DÖNÜŞ","112-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ALT GEÇİT FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","114-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ÜST GEÇIT FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","110-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ÜST GEÇIT GİDİŞ","113-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ÜST GEÇIT KARADENİZ CAD. GİDİŞ","110-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ÜST GEÇİT DÖNÜŞ","113-GOP KOCASİNAN TEPEEVLER ÜST GEÇİT KARADENİZ CAD. DÖNÜŞ","410-GÖKKENT DÖNÜŞ","410-GÖKKENT GİDİŞ","411-GÖKKENT TAVLUSUN DÖNÜŞ","235-GÖMEÇ DÖNÜŞ","232-GÖMEÇ DÖNÜŞ","232-GÖMEÇ GİDİŞ","418-GÜL SİTESİ DÖNÜŞ","418-GÜL SİTESİ GİDİŞ","744-GÜLLÜCE DNS","744-GÜLLÜCE GDS","30-GÜLTEPE DÖNÜŞ","30-GÜLTEPE GİDİŞ","380-GÜNEŞLİ DÖNÜŞ","380-GÜNEŞLİ GİDİŞ","381-GÜNEŞLİ GÖMEÇ DÖNÜŞ","381-GÜNEŞLİ GÖMEÇ GİDİŞ","382-GÜNEŞLİ KIZIK DÖNÜŞ","382-GÜNEŞLİ KIZIK GİDİŞ","529-GÜRPINAR DÖNÜŞ","529-GÜRPINAR GİDİŞ","64-GÜRSOY HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","64-GÜRSOY HASTANE GİDİŞ","572-HACILAR  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","572-HACILAR  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","576-HACILAR AĞAÇİŞLERİ GİDİŞ","574-HACILAR AKDAM MH. DÖNÜŞ","574-HACILAR AKDAM MH. GİDİŞ","5701-HACILAR DÖNÜŞ","570-HACILAR DÖNÜŞ","570-HACILAR GİDİŞ","575-HACILAR ORGANİZE DÖNÜŞ","575-HACILAR ORGANİZE GİDİŞ","571-HACILAR SERVER DÖNÜŞ","571-HACILAR SERVER GİDİŞ","5711-HACILAR SERVER GİDİŞ","344-HACILAR ULUYER DÖNÜŞ","344-HACILAR ULUYER GİDİŞ","183-HAKİMİYET YENİŞEHİR HASTANE GİDİŞ","182-HAKİMİYET YENİŞEHİR İSTASYON DÖNÜŞ","182-HAKİMİYET YENİŞEHİR İSTASYON GİDİŞ","346-HASAN DAĞI (HACILAR) DÖNÜŞ","346-HASAN DAĞI (HACILAR) GİDİŞ","804-HASİNLİ- KARAKİMSE-KALKANCIK DNS","804-HASİNLİ-KARAKİMSE-KALKANCIK DNS","804-HASİNLİ-KARAKİMSE-KALKANCIK GDS","804-HASİNLİ-KARAKİMSE-KALKANCIK GDS","806-HIRKAKÖY ESKİÖMERLER  DNS","806-HIRKAKÖY ESKİÖMERLER  DNS","711-HİMMETDEDE- DÜVER HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","711-HİMMETDEDE- DÜVER HASTANE GİDİŞ","710-HİMMETDEDE HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","710-HİMMETDEDE HASTANE GİDİŞ","712-HİMMETDEDE- KAŞ HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","712-HİMMETDEDE- KAŞ HASTANE GİDİŞ","4901-HİSARCIK ÇAKIL SOKAK DÖNÜŞ","490-HİSARCIK DÖNÜŞ","491-HİSARCIK FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","490-HİSARCIK GİDİŞ","4902-HİSARCIK KORUDİBİ DÖNÜŞ","4903-HİSARCIK ORAK SOKAK GİDİŞ","492-HİSARCIK SSK YENİ SANAYİ DÖNÜŞ","420-HÖRMETÇİ DÖNÜŞ","420-HÖRMETÇİ GİDİŞ","63-HÜRRİYET AKKAYA DÖNÜŞ","63-HÜRRİYET AKKAYA GİDİŞ","62-HÜRRİYET FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","62-HÜRRİYET FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","61-HÜRRİYET 06:30 DÖNÜŞ","61-HÜRRİYET 06:30 GİDİŞ","60-HÜRRİYET 6:00 KOÇAK DÖNÜŞ","60-HÜRRİYET 6:00 KOÇAK GİDİŞ","512-hatlar  FATİH  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","512-hatlar  FATİH  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","514-hatlar  FATİH ÇEVREYOL HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","515-hatlar  FATİH ÇEVREYOL HASTANE FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","512-hatlar  FATİH FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","512-hatlar  FATİH FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","517-hatlar BELSİN  DÖNÜŞ","517-hatlar BELSİN  GİDİŞ","518-hatlar BELSİN ORGANİZE GECE SERVİS DÖNÜŞ","518-hatlar BELSİN ORGANİZE GECE SERVİSİ GİDİŞ","511-hatlar FATİH D.TAŞER CAD. DÖNÜŞ","511-hatlar FATİH D.TAŞER CAD. GİDİŞ","513-hatlar FATİH MAH. HASTANE","510-hatlar FATİH S.A.BEDÜK CAD. DNS","510-hatlar FATİH S.A.BEDÜK CAD. GDS","530-İNCESU DÖNÜŞ","531-İNCESU HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","539-İNCESU HASTANE FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","532-İNCESU İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","532-İNCESU İMAMHATİP FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","534-İNCESU KARAKOYUNLU DÖNÜŞ","534-İNCESU KARAKOYUNLU GİDİŞ","535-İNCESU SEMERKENT GİDİŞ","748-KARAKAYA DNS","748-KARAKAYA GDS","162-KAYABAŞI FUZULI FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","162-KAYABAŞI FUZULI FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","164-KAYABAŞI HASTANE  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","167-KAYABAŞI HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","160-KAYABAŞI HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","160-KAYABAŞI HASTANE GİDİŞ","167-KAYABAŞI HASTANE GİDİŞ","165-KAYABAŞI NATO CAD. DÖNÜŞ","165-KAYABAŞI NATO CAD. GİDİŞ","166-KAYABAŞI SAĞLIK OCAĞI DÖNÜŞ","166-KAYABAŞI SAĞLIK OCAĞI GİDİŞ","71-KAZIM KARABEKİR FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","71-KAZIM KARABEKİR FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","72-KAZIM KARABEKİR HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","72-KAZIM KARABEKİR HASTANE GİDİŞ","70-KAZIM KARABEKİR İMAMHATİP DÖNÜŞ","70-KAZIM KARABEKİR İMAMHATİP GİDİŞ","22-KEÇİTEPESİ KÖŞK MAH.FAKÜLTEDÖNÜŞ","22-KEÇİTEPESİ KÖŞK MAH.FAKÜLTEGİDİŞ","24-KEÇİTEPESİ M.ŞİMŞEK FAKÜLTEDÖNÜŞ","24-KEÇİTEPESİ M.ŞİMŞEK FAKÜLTEGİDİŞ","582-KEPEZ CEBİR YAZYURDU TALAS İÇİ DÖNÜŞ","582-KEPEZ CEBİR YAZYURDU TALAS İÇİ GİDİŞ","581-KEPEZ-CEBİR-YAZILI DAĞYOLU DÖNÜŞ","581-KEPEZ-CEBİR-YAZILI DAĞYOLU GİDİŞ","495-KIRANARDI  ENDÜRLÜK GİDİŞ","496-KIRANARDI  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","499-KIRANARDI  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","495-KIRANARDI DÖNÜŞ","495-KIRANARDI GİDİŞ","498-KIRANARDI HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","497-KIRANARDI SANAYİ DÖNÜŞ","495-KIRANARDI YEŞİLDERE DÖNÜŞ","476-KIZIK SALUR DÖNÜŞ","476-KIZIK SALUR GİDİŞ","428-KIZILÖREN DÖNÜŞ","428-KIZILÖREN GİDİŞ","58-KIZILTEPE DÖNÜŞ","58-KIZILTEPE GİDİŞ","269-KOCASİNAN SİNANKENT DÖNÜŞ","269-KOCASİNAN SİNANKENT GİDİŞ","389-KONAKLAR FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","389-KONAKLAR FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","393-KONAKLAR GİDİŞ","391-KONAKLAR YILDIRIM BEYAZIT DÖNÜŞ","391-KONAKLAR YILDIRIM BEYAZIT GİDİŞ","393-KONAKLAR 06:40 DÖNÜŞ","351-KÖPRÜBAŞI HASTANE CAD. DÖNÜŞ","350-KÖPRÜBAŞI SİVAS CAD. GİDİŞ","75-KULAKLI SEYRANTEPE DÖNÜŞ","75-KULAKLI SEYRANTEPE GİDİŞ","475-KUŞÇU-BOYACI DÖNÜŞ","475-KUŞÇU-BOYACI GİDİŞ","406-MAHZEMİN DÖNÜŞ","406-MAHZEMİN GİDİŞ","408-MAHZEMİN HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","408-MAHZEMİN HASTANE GİDİŞ","635-MELİKGAZİ  SOSYAL KONUTLAR DÖNÜŞ","635-MELİKGAZİ  SOSYAL KONUTLAR GİDİŞ","563-MELİKŞAH ANAYURT DÖNÜŞ","563-MELİKŞAH ANAYURT GİDİŞ","100-MEVLANA HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","100-MEVLANA HASTANE GİDİŞ","102-MEVLANA İSTASYON FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","102-MEVLANA İSTASYON FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","250-MİMAR SİNAN  UGUREVLER DÖNÜŞ","250-MİMAR SİNAN  UGUREVLER GİDİŞ","376-MİMARSİNAN  ORGANİZE DÖNÜŞ","376-MİMARSİNAN  ORGANİZE GİDİŞ","450-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN  DÖNÜŞ","450-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN  GİDİŞ","453-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN ÇEVREYOL SANAYİ DÖNÜŞ","453-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN ÇEVREYOL SANAYİ GİDİŞ","451-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN FAKÜLTE  DÖNÜŞ","451-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN FAKÜLTE  GİDİŞ","454-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN FATİH HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","4501-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN GİDİŞ","452-MİMARSİNAN MİMSİN HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","4551-MİMSİN FATİH MAH.","455-MİMSİN FATİH MAH.  DÖNÜŞ","455-MİMSİN FATİH MAH.  GİDİŞ","456-MİMSİN FATİH MAH. FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","456-MİMSİN FATİH MAH. FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","241-MİTHATPAŞA HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","241-MİTHATPAŞA HASTANE GİDİŞ","240-MİTHATPAŞA NATO CAD. DÖNÜŞ","243-MİTHATPAŞA NATO CAD FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","243-MİTHATPAŞA NATO CAD. FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","430-MOLU-OYMAAĞAÇ DÖNÜŞ","430-MOLU-OYMAAĞAÇ GİDİŞ","270-NATO 200 EVLER FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","640-NUH NACİ YAZGAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ DÖNÜŞ","640-NUH NACİ YAZGAN ÜNİVERSİTESİ GİDİŞ","371-ORGANİZE RİNG 12. CADDE","370-ORGANİZE RİNG 24. CADDE","374-ORGANİZE SERBEST BÖLGE DÖNÜŞ","374-ORGANİZE SERBEST BÖLGE GİDİŞ","211-ORUÇREİS HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","211-ORUÇREİS HASTANE GİDİŞ","214-ORUÇREİS HOBİ GİDİŞ","212-ORUÇREİS İSTASYON  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","213-ORUÇREİS İSTASYON CAD. HOBİ BAH.","210-ORUÇREİS İSTASYON DÖNÜŞ","210-ORUÇREİS İSTASYON GİDİŞ","223-OSMANLI MAH.  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","223-OSMANLI MAH.  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","222-OSMANLI MAH. DÖNÜŞ","222-OSMANLI MAH. GİDİŞ","424-ÖRENŞEHİR HAMURCU İ.HATİP DÖNÜŞ","424-ÖRENŞEHİR HAMURCU İ.HATİP GİDİŞ","315-PELIT BELBASI DÖNÜŞ","315-PELIT BELBASI GİDİŞ","150-PERVANE DÖNÜŞ","150-PERVANE GİDİŞ","487-POLİS OKULU SÜMEREVLERİ DÖNÜŞ","487-POLİS OKULU SÜMEREVLERİ GİDİŞ","549-REŞADİYE ZİNCİDERE BAŞAKPINAR DAĞYOLU GİDİŞ","548-REŞADİYE ZİNCİDERE BAŞAKPINAR TALAS GİDİŞ","342-SAKAR-EŞMECIK DÖNÜŞ","342-SAKAR-EŞMECIK GİDİŞ","206-SANCAKTEPE DÖNÜŞ","206-SANCAKTEPE GİDİŞ","233-SARIMSAKLI DÖNÜŞ","233-SARIMSAKLI GİDİŞ","48-SELÇUKLU AŞAĞI  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","48-SELÇUKLU AŞAĞI  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","47-SELÇUKLU AŞAĞI DÖNÜŞ","47-SELÇUKLU AŞAĞI GİDİŞ","45-SELÇUKLU KÜÇÜKALİ DÖNÜŞ","45-SELÇUKLU KÜÇÜKALİ GİDİŞ","44-SELÇUKLU YUKARI  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","44-SELÇUKLU YUKARI  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","43-SELÇUKLU YUKARI DÖNÜŞ","43-SELÇUKLU YUKARI GİDİŞ","49-SELÇUKLU YUKARI KÜÇÜKALİ DÖNÜŞ","49-SELÇUKLU YUKARI KÜÇÜKALİ GİDİŞ","262-SİNANKENT KOCASİNAN ATAŞEHİR DÖNÜŞ","262-SİNANKENT KOCASİNAN ATAŞEHİR GİDİŞ","317-SUDEPOSU DÖNÜŞ","317-SUDEPOSU GİDİŞ","404-SÜKSÜN DÖNÜŞ","404-SÜKSÜN GİDİŞ","280-ŞEKER TEPEEVLER ALTGEÇIT DÖNÜŞ","280-ŞEKER TEPEEVLER ALTGEÇIT GİDİŞ","281-ŞEKER TEPEEVLER ÜSTGEÇIT DÖNÜŞ","281-ŞEKER TEPEEVLER ÜSTGEÇIT GİDİŞ","814-TAHİRİNLİ-KÜLLÜ-KARAHÜYÜK DNS","814-TAHİRİNLİ-KÜLLÜ-KARAHÜYÜK GDS","566-TALAS ANAŞEHİR DÖNÜŞ","566-TALAS ANAŞEHİR GİDİŞ","550-TALAS ANAYURT JANDARMA DÖNÜŞ","550-TALAS ANAYURT JANDARMA GİDİŞ","551-TALAS ANAYURT MEYSU DÖNÜŞ","551-TALAS ANAYURT MEYSU GİDİŞ","552-TALAS ANAYURT TUT DÖNÜŞ","552-TALAS ANAYURT TUT KAVŞAĞI GİDİŞ","560-TALAS BAHÇELİEVLER DÖNÜŞ","560-TALAS BAHÇELİEVLER GİDİŞ","568-TALAS FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","568-TALAS FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","569-TALAS GECE SERVİSİ DÖNÜŞ","569-TALAS GECE SERVİSİ GİDİŞ","562-TALAS HASTANE  DÖNÜŞ ","562-TALAS HASTANE  GİDİŞ","567-TALAS hatlar DÖNÜŞ","567-TALAS hatlar GİDİŞ","561-TALAS SİVAS CAD. BELSİN DÖNÜŞ","561-TALAS SİVAS CAD. BELSİN GİDİŞ","565-TALAS YENİ SANAYİ DÖNÜŞ","565-TALAS YENİ SANAYİ GİDİŞ","557-TALAS YENİDOĞAN DÖNÜŞ","557-TALAS YENİDOĞAN GİDİŞ","558-TALAS 6. ETAP DÖNÜŞ","558-TALAS 6. ETAP GİDİŞ","355-TALATPAŞA HASTANE CAD. GİDİŞ","356-TALATPAŞA SİVAS CAD. DÖNÜŞ","416-TAVLUSUN DÖNÜŞ","416-TAVLUSUN GİDİŞ","591-TOKİ AŞAĞI  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","591-TOKİ AŞAĞI  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","590-TOKİ AŞAĞI DÖNÜŞ","590-TOKİ AŞAĞI GİDİŞ","588-TOKİ HASTANE DÖNŞ","588-TOKİ HASTANE GİDİŞ","596-TOKİ YUKARI SERKENT  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","596-TOKİ YUKARI SERKENT  FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","595-TOKİ YUKARI SERKENT DÖNÜŞ","595-TOKİ YUKARI SERKENT GİDİŞ","589-TOKİ 8. ETAP GİDİŞ","589-TOKİ 8.ETAP DÖNÜŞ","528-TURAN BÜRÜNGÜZ DÖNÜŞ","528-TURAN BÜRÜNGÜZ GİDİŞ","20-Y. BEYAZIT DÖNÜŞ","308-YAKUT MAH. DNS","308-YAKUT MAH. GDS","261-YAVUZSELİM DÖNÜŞ","261-YAVUZSELİM GİDİŞ","20-Y.BEYAZIT GİDİŞ","716-YEMLİHA HASTANE DNS","716-YEMLİHA HASTANE GDS","80-YENİ MAH. DÖNÜŞ","81-YENİ MAH. FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","81-YENİ MAH. FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","80-YENİ MAH. GİDİŞ","360-YENİ MAH YENİŞEHİR DÖNÜŞ","360-YENİ MAH YENİŞEHİR GİDİŞ","746-YENİSÜKSÜN DNS","746-YENİSÜKSÜN GDS","180-YENİŞEHİR HAKİMİYET FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","184-YENİŞEHİR HAKİMİYET HASTANE FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","186-YENİŞEHİR HAKİMİYET HASTANE İNÖNÜ BULV. FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","181-YENİŞEHİR HAKİMİYET İSTASYON FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","191-YEŞİL MAH. ALT GEÇİT HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","190-YEŞİL MAH. ALT GEÇİT İSTASYON DÖNÜŞ","192-YEŞİL MAH. ÜST GEÇİT İSTASYON CAD. DÖNÜŞ","191-YEŞİL MAHALLE HASTANE ALTGEÇİT GİDİŞ","193-YEŞİL MAHALLE HASTANE ÜSTGEÇİT DÖNÜŞ","190-YEŞİL MAHALLE İSTASYON ALTGEÇİT GİDİŞ","230-YEŞİLYURT BAĞPINAR DÖNÜŞ","230-YEŞİLYURT BAĞPINAR GİDİŞ","230-YEŞİLYURT DÖNÜŞ","230-YEŞİLYURT GİDİŞ","392-YILDIRIM BEYAZIT KONAKLAR DÖNÜŞ","392-YILDIRIM BEYAZIT KONAKLAR GİDİŞ","170-YILDIZEVLER FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","170-YILDIZEVLER FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","616-ZİNCİDERE DAĞYOLU DÖNÜŞ","616-ZİNCİDERE DAĞYOLU GİDİŞ","615-ZİNCİDERE TALAS İÇİ DÖNÜŞ","615-ZİNCİDERE TALAS İÇİ GİDİŞ","285-ZİYAGÖKALP FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","285-ZİYAGÖKALP FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","287-ZİYAGÖKALP YENİDOĞAN FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","300-ZÜMRÜT HASTANE  GİDİŞ","300-ZÜMRÜT HASTANE DÖNÜŞ","301-ZÜMRÜT HASTANE FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","301-ZÜMRÜT HASTANE FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","302-ZÜMRÜT NATO  FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","303-ZÜMRÜT NATO DÖNÜŞ","302-ZÜMRÜT NATO FAKÜLTE GİDİŞ","303-ZÜMRÜT NATO GİDİŞ","270-200 EVLER NATO FAKÜLTE DÖNÜŞ","559-6. ETAP SİVAS CAD. DÖNÜŞ","559-6. ETAP SİVAS CAD. GİDİŞ","555-62 EVLER CEMİL BABA DÖNÜŞ","555-62 EVLER CEMİL BABA GİDİŞ","556-62 EVLER ÇAMLIBEL DÖNÜŞ","556-62 EVLER ÇAMLIBEL GİDİŞ"};

final String[] busline0 = {"H. İçi","C.tesi","Pazar","06:00","06:00","---------","07:00","07:00","07:00","08:00","08:00","---------","---------","09:00","10:00","10:00","---------","11:00","11:00","11:00","13:00","13:00","13:00","15:00","15:00","15:00","16:30\nTakviye","16:30\nTakviye","---------","---------","---------","17:00","17:15","17:15","---------","19:00","19:00","19:00","21:00","21:00","21:00","23:00","23:00","23:00"};

final String[] busline1={"07:00","07:00","---------","08:00","08:00","08:00","10:00","10:00","10:00","11:00","11:00","---------","---------","---------","12:00","13:00","13:00","---------","---------","---------","14:00","15:00","15:00","---------","15:30 Takviye","15:30 Takviye"," 16:00","16:15","16:15","---------","17:30 Takviye","17:30 Takviye ","18:00","18:00","18:00","19:00Takviye","---------","19:00Takviye","20:00","20:00","20:00","22:00","22:00","22:00","23:45","23:45","23:45"};
.
. the other line times...




ArrayAdapter<String> adapterbir = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Otobus.this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, hatlar);
adapterbir.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item); // The drop down view
spinner1.setAdapter(adapterbir);


spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, final int position,long id) {


                      String linename=("busline"+String.valueOf(position));
                        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                      int i=0;
                      for (String s : linename){ // Error here:Can only iterate over an array or an instance of java.lang.Iterable
                        i++;
                            if (i%3==0){ //using below code block to print times as 3 columns and it works...
                          builder.append(s+"\n");
                      cikti.setText(builder.toString());
                            }
                            else if (i%3!=0)
                            {
                                 builder.append(s+" "+" "+" "+" "+" "+" ");
                           //Textview's name is cikti :)     
                             cikti.setText(builder.toString());
                            }
                      }
```

Comment: As the error says, linename is a string not the string array `String[]` but just a single string instance. You may have wanted `buslines`, `busline0` or `busline1`

Comment: That's not the way you iterate over a `String`

Answer (score 0):

```
String linename=("busline"+String.valueOf(position));
... 
for (String s : linename) // should be an array (e.g. "buslines")
```

This raises an error because `linename` is not an array but a `String`.
Did you mean `buslines` ?

Comment: No. Buslines array contains line names. But linename variable contains only one line's bus times. For example linename value=busline0 or busline1 or busline400. So i want to use linename variable to referencing arrays that containing bus times.

Comment: Sorry but i really can't understand this : `So i want to use linename variable to referencing arrays that containing bus times.`

Answer (score 0):

in your case `linename` is a `String` so you can't iterate it. I'm not sure what you want to achive but if you want to go through every letter the iterate in standard `for` loop with counter and use `charAt(counter)`

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I understood from your comment.

*linename value=busline0 or busline1 or busline400. So i want to use linename variable to referencing arrays that containing bus times.*

You have an index after `busline`, and you want to use this index to get the element from your array.

To get the index use `substring` method.

```
String busname = "busline123";
String indexValue = busname.substring(7);//returns 123
String []timings = {"10:20", "11:30", .....};
System.out.println("The timing for index " + indexValue + " would be " + timings[Integer.parseInt(indexValue)]);
```

Comment: No i dont want to get element from my array i want to get an array with all elements to listing bus times.

Comment: Then you must give us a little more clarity of how you want to do it.